# Equivalent of metadata:schema

Tags: arcadedb

Please can someone explain the equivalent of `SELECT expand(classes) FROM metadata:schema LIMIT 100` from OrientDB in ArcadeDB ? I've obviously tried the query and also `expand(types)` instead but neither work.

Answer (score 1):

Found it:

To query the schema you can use:

`select from schema:types` to retrieve the defined types

`select from schema:indexes` to retrieve the defined indexes

`select from schema:database` to retrieve information about database settings